# jsfiddle.net and the html iframe (the html textarea)

Tags: jsfiddle

Since yesterday I can't read and write the html in jsfiddle, field is empty…
I try with chrome, ff, safari, and have same result in private mode.
I try a Google search about this and found nothing. I am on mac os x 10.6.8.

Comment: We had nothing scheduled. BTW, this type of discussion shouldn't happen on SO, please come to https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-docs-alpha/issues

Answer (score -2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/E4mz9/25/

They are saying that they are performing maintenance and that is why the box is not editable:

```
// Hi there,
//
// We're moving and improving the jsFiddle servers to create a better
// service for everyone.
//
// While that's happening - there is read only access only.
// You will be able to view fiddles but any editing will be lost.
//
// When migration of the site is complete, this temporary version of
// the database will be deleted to avoid misunderstandings. Your
// fiddles are safe, you just can't edit them right now.
//
// TL;DR
//   - jsFiddle is moving servers.
//   - For the next couple of hours:
//      - Save is disabled
//      - Registration is disabled
//
// Thanks for your patience,
//
// jsFiddle team.
//
// :D
```

Comment: Thank you, I found nothing on the blog…

Comment: when have you seen this comment? We haven't been doing that since January ... If it's just loaded from that fiddle then don't worry it has been created for the servers move